# Выбрать и скрыть value в select по условиям

Tags: jquery

У меня есть следующий скрипт. 
При выборе connectid value="1 в presentId должн показываться только value="1"
При выборе connectid value="7 в presentId должн показываться только value="1" и в inbound_from value 1, 6, 8
а в остальных случаях connectid value= 1,4,5,6.9 должн показываться только value="2 и в inbound_from value(показывались все)

На данный момент работает так: 
Когда выбираю connectid value= 1 показывается в presentId value="1 и 2 (а должен только 1)
Когда выбираю connectid value= 7 показывается в presentId value="1 и 2 (а должен только 1) и inbound_from(показываются все) а нужно 1,6,8
Когда выбираю connectid value= 2,4,5,6,9 показывается в presentId value="1 и 2 (а должен только 2) и inbound_from(показываются все)

HTML:

```
<select id="connectid" name="conectId">
   <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
   <option value="1">ТЕЛЕФОН</option>
   <option value="2">ИНТЕРНЕТ</option>
   <option value="4">ПОСЕЩЕНИЕ</option>
   <option value="5">ПРЕДСТАВИТЕЛЬ</option>
   <option value="6">ПОЧТА</option>
   <option value="7">ГОРЯЧАЯ ЛИНИЯ</option>
   <option value="9">ЛИЧНЫЙ ПРИЁМ</option>
</select>
<select id="presentId" name="presentId" onclick="changepresentId()">
    <option value="1">УСТНОЕ</option>
    <option value="2">ПИСЬМЕННОЕ</option>
</select>
<select id="inbound_from" name="blockger2016.inbound_from" style=
"display: none;">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">От кого</option>
    <option value="1">ГРАЖДАНИНОМ (ЛИЧНО)</option>
    <option value="2">Ф1</option>
    <option value="3">Т1</option>
    <option value="4">С1</option>
    <option value="5">З1</option>
    <option value="6">Р1</option>
    <option value="7">Р2</option>
    <option value="8">М1</option>
    <option value="9">С1</option>
    <option value="10">А1</option>
    <option value="11">М2</option>
    <option value="12">Т1</option>
    <option value="100">П1</option>
</select>
```

JQuery;

```
function changepresentId() {
            if (($("#presentId" ).val() ==1 && ($("#connectid" ).val() !=1 && $("#connectid" ).val() !=7))
                || ($("#presentId").val() ==2 && ($("#connectid" ).val() ==1 || $("#connectid" ).val() ==7))
                || ($("#presentId").val() ==1 && $("#connectid").val() ==1))


        {   //Блокировка
                $('#inboundLetter').fadeOut();
                $('#inbound_from').fadeOut();
                $('#addpetit').fadeIn();
                $('#sel').fadeIn(); 
        }else{//Открытие

             $('#inboundLetter').fadeIn();
                $('#inbound_from').fadeIn();
                $('#addpetit').fadeOut();
                $('#sel').fadeOut();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не люблю я jQuery, потому JS:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  /* Делегируем обработчик для всех селектов */
  document.querySelector('.forma').addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
    // Отклоняем самовызов, при установке значения скриптом
    if (!ev.isTrusted) { return }
    /* Инициализация объектов и переменных */
    let oLinkType = document.querySelector('#connectid');
    let oFormType = document.querySelector('#presentId');
    let oFromWhom = document.querySelector('#inbound_from');
    let oTarget = ev.target;
    let sSelVal = oTarget.options[oTarget.selectedIndex].value;
    // Если выбор произошёл в "connectid", тогда...
    if (oTarget == oLinkType) {
      /* Выполняем действия в соответствии с выбором */
      if (sSelVal == '1') {
        fShowRequiredItems(oFormType, ['1'], 0);
        fShowRequiredItems(oFromWhom, ['1']);
      } else if (sSelVal == '7') {
        fShowRequiredItems(oFormType, ['1'], 0);
        fShowRequiredItems(oFromWhom, ['1', '6', '8']);
      } else {
        fShowRequiredItems(oFormType, ['2'], 1);
        fShowRequiredItems(oFromWhom, ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '100']);
      }
      changepresentId();
      /* Иначе, если нужны действия при выборе в других списках... */
    } else if (oTarget == oFormType) {
    } else if (oTarget == oFromWhom) {

    }
  });
  /* Скрытие/показ и выбор только нужных пунктов в списке 
      oObj - объект "select" 
      aItems - массив значений "value" пунктов, которые следует отобразить
      nDefault - числовой индекс пункта, который будет выбран после изменений
  */
  function fShowRequiredItems(oObj, aItems, nDefault) {
    // Массив "option"
    let aOpt = Array.prototype.slice.call(oObj.querySelectorAll('option'));
    // Перебор массива "option"
    aOpt.forEach(function(item, index) {
      // Если "value" содержится в "видимых", тогда "block", иначе "none"
      item.style.display = (aItems.includes(item.value)) ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
    // Если передан выбор "по умолчанию", тогда...
    if (nDefault !== undefined) {
      // Выбираем пункт "по умолчанию"
      oObj.options[nDefault].selected = true;
    }
  }
});

function changepresentId() {
  if (($("#presentId").val() == 1 && ($("#connectid").val() != 1 && $("#connectid").val() != 7)) || ($("#presentId").val() == 2 && ($("#connectid").val() == 1 || $("#connectid").val() == 7)) || ($("#presentId").val() == 1 && $("#connectid").val() == 1)) {
    //Блокировка
    $('#inboundLetter').fadeOut();
    $('#inbound_from').fadeOut();
    $('#addpetit').fadeIn();
    $('#sel').fadeIn();
  } else {
    //Открытие
    $('#inboundLetter').fadeIn();
    $('#inbound_from').fadeIn();
    $('#addpetit').fadeOut();
    $('#sel').fadeOut();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="forma">

  <select id="connectid" name="conectId">
    <option value="" disabled selected></option>
    <option value="1">ТЕЛЕФОН</option>
    <option value="2">ИНТЕРНЕТ</option>
    <option value="4">ПОСЕЩЕНИЕ</option>
    <option value="5">ПРЕДСТАВИТЕЛЬ</option>
    <option value="6">ПОЧТА</option>
    <option value="7">ГОРЯЧАЯ ЛИНИЯ</option>
    <option value="9">ЛИЧНЫЙ ПРИЁМ</option>
  </select>

  <select id="presentId" name="presentId" onclick="changepresentId()">
    <option value="1">УСТНОЕ</option>
    <option value="2">ПИСЬМЕННОЕ</option>
  </select>

  <select id="inbound_from" name="blockger2016.inbound_from" style="display: none;">
    <option value="" disabled selected>От кого</option>
    <option value="1">ГРАЖДАНИНОМ (ЛИЧНО)</option>
    <option value="2">Ф1</option>
    <option value="3">Т1</option>
    <option value="4">С1</option>
    <option value="5">З1</option>
    <option value="6">Р1</option>
    <option value="7">Р2</option>
    <option value="8">М1</option>
    <option value="9">С1</option>
    <option value="10">А1</option>
    <option value="11">М2</option>
    <option value="12">Т1</option>
    <option value="100">П1</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Что-то у меня выдает ошибки. Как оформить правильно JavaScript правильно

Comment: @dmr здесь на сайте превью работает? Если да, то браузер и текст ошибки, будьте добры.